# Lenovo ideapad320 laptop(amd a9 processor) touchpad is not working Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, cpu

I am using Lenovo IdeaPad320 laptop (AMD A9 processor). Touchpad is not working after installing Ubuntu 17.10. Its working before the login but after that not working.

Comment: can you show us the list of all startup applications you have?

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 on a ideapad320 AMD A12th gen , kernel 4.13.0.-32-generic and my touchpad stopped working even after rebooting

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to linux kernel 4.15 or above. Ubuntu 18.04 uses 4.15, so install that.

I have the exact same machine. Ubuntu 18.04 works just fine, though the boot time is a little long.